# Problem while printing Hindi text through a user defined function!

Tags: php, unicode, printing

I how two php files one is main.php and second is functions.php. If I print below line in main.php, its working fine.

print "देश विदेश";

but my reqirment is to call a function from functions.php in main.php that should do the same:

`Mian.php`

```
require_once('functions.php');
print func_headline();
```

`functions.php`

```
function func_headline()
{
 //print html_entity_decode("देश विदेश", ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
print "देश विदेश";
//utf8_encode("<a title='देश विदेश' href='#'><span>'देश विदेश'</span></a>");
}
```

why it doesnot works??

Answer (score 0):

You need to just call the function in `main.php`. Change statement

```
print func_headline();
```

to

```
 func_headline();
```